# Dynamic input fields for database insert

Tags: javascript, html, sql

I'm working on a project where the user will get an online form they have to fill out with items.
I have many different labels for personal data and one label for the item name, that they will have to select from a dropdown (items come from the database).

```
<label id="first">Item name</label><br/>
<select name="itemname" required>
    <?php 
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM items");
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
        $naziv = $row['name'];
    echo '<option value="'.$naziv .'">'.$naziv .'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select><br/>
```

Now this code is working perfectly, and I also have a quantity field for it.
Now, I don't have a clue how I could add the option to add multiple input fields without having to declare many more database columns and separate inputs for each one. Could I somehow do this dinamically?

Comment: Are you talking about creating a list of <input> tags, each with a <label>? If so, how about creating a database table called "inputs"?

Comment: Each form has a field named Item name and Item quantity. Item name has a dropdown of all items. I'm trying to add like 15 fields for both of them without having to have 15 columns for it in my database. 
Database: id, itemname, itemquantity, date, personaldata...

Comment: You have multiple forms? What is the source for these 15 fields? Still confused. Can you post an example of the completed HTML?

Comment: I currently don't have my files with me but imagine, that a user has a reciept where they enter personal data. On the reciept they enter a maximum of 15 items but a minimum of 1. The source for them is a database with all items, and the fields should post their content to the database. I'm not sure how to form a database for allowing multiple items on one reciept that users can input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a database structure that permits receipts that can contain multiple items.

You need multiple tables.

Create a new table called 'receipts':

```
TABLE receipts: id, (...personal data)
```

Add a field to the items table called "receipt_id".

```
TABLE items: id, receipt_id, itemname, itemquantity, date
```

You should also have a separate table to contain the available item names, which you use to populate the `<select>`, above:

```
TABLE itemnames: id, name, (description?)
```

Comment: I've been thinking in this direction but how could I implement this on the html form? For example, the user can click a + sign to add more items?

Comment: You'll need to write a JavaScript function that adds new inputs to the form.